# Cross reference between 2 tables using column values and add row from another table if no match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie and it feels like I am over-complicating my situation.
I have 2 different tables. 1 is the Main Table and Table 2 pulling data from another website.
I want to copy any row from table 2 that are not existing in the main table using the values from the "State" column. I have searched all over and tried copying and modifying codes (index, vlookup, countif, etc.) to my need but no luck. I feel like theres a simple solution to this. Please assist. TY!

(VBA code preferred as my tables are dynamic being a csv data pull. using the table header would be the better option than setting a fixed cell range.)

| State | Units |
| --- | --- |
| California | 10 |
| New York | 20 |
| New Jersey | 30 |
| Texas | 40 |

| State | Units | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | 10 | L8S5 |
| New York | 20 | 82IO |
| New Jersey | 30 | WT2N |
| Texas | 40 | TSE0 |
| Florida | 50 | F23V |
| Ohio | 60 | J2D1 |
| Arizona | 70 | 55S8 |

The closest answer to my problem is in this tread but I could not make it work.

[Searching Between 2 Sheets for Matches and Adding New Row If No Match Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353346/searching-between-2-sheets-for-matches-and-adding-new-row-if-no-match-found)

Comment: Your table-1 has 2 columns, your table-2 has 3 columns. Say your table-1 "STATE" is from A2 to A5. The expected result in table-1 is :  Florida in A6, Ohio in A7, Arizona in A8. 50 in B6, 60 in B7, 70 in B8. F23V in C6. J2D1 in C7. 55S8 in C8. Please correct me if I;m wrong.

Comment: That is correct! My actual table has about 15 columns. Some I need, and some don't. Hopefully you can help me with being able to choose between the columns. Thank you, very much appreciated!

Comment: @karma any updates by any chance? thanks